# How can I create 2 executable in 1 Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android.mk file which create 1 executable 'main1'

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= file3.c \
    file2.c \
    main2.c \
    file1.c \
    main1.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= main1
```

How can I add 'main2.c' so that it a 2nd executable 'main2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main2.c is already listed as a source for module main1. Just saying.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= file3.c \
    file2.c \
    main2.c \
    file1.c \
    main1.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= main1
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

# And start anew
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= main2.c

LOCAL_MODULE:= main2
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```